# Firefox YouTube videos often refuse to load after a certain duration into the video

Tags: firefox, video, browser, youtube

I have recently switched from using Google Chrome to using Mozilla Firefox, but have noticed some problems with YouTube videos, very often, I play a video, but it refuses to load more than half of the video (can be less or more), and no matter what I do, I cannot get it to play beyond that point, and sometimes even after refreshing the page it does not work, this is very annoying, so I am wondering if there is any fix for this? If you wish for me to provide any more information, please just comment and I will do so.

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

### Package Information:

```
firefox:
  Installed: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Flash problem, not a Firefox problem…

I use the following workaround (this is not a solution, maybe someone else will have a better idea, but in the mean time, it'll help):

- Note the time you're stuck in the video
- Do a hard refresh <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
- Play the video again and click on the time just before you had the problem.

This seems to work in 90% of all cases.  If not, I just note the time, quit Firefox, saving all tabs, wait for 3 seconds, start Firefox up again and continue again.  This brings you up to 99% of all cases solved.

Then there's always log off and log on again (99,9%) and reboot (99,99%)